# How to make pycassa silent (make it stop printing to console when i create or change key or column validators)

Tags: pycassa

The following prints "DoubleType(reversed=false)" to the console; how do i tell pycassa to stop doing that? It happens when i alter_column too.

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Nov 30 2011, 19:22:03) 
[GCC 4.6.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pycassa.types import CompositeType, UTF8Type, LongType, DoubleType, BooleanType
>>> from pycassa.system_manager import SystemManager
>>> SystemManager().create_keyspace('test', strategy_options={"replication_factor": "1"})
>>> SystemManager().create_column_family('test', 'testcf', key_validation_class=DoubleType())
DoubleType(reversed=false)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a harmless bug that was fixed here: https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa/issues/98

The next release won't have this issue.